# Constructor on type (...) not found when that type HAS a constructor

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to find all classes with the custom attribute "ToolTestAttribute" and instantiate an instance of that class. When the code tries to run the constructor it is reporting that the constructor type is not found.

My class I am trying to start looks like this:

```
    public AllComponentsConstrained(ITool toolFile) 
    {
        tool = toolFile;
    }
```

My code that finds the classes with the attribute I need looks like this:

```
        List<object> StartTests(Assembly assem, ITool tool)
    {
        List<object> result = new List<object>();
        foreach (Type type in assem.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ToolTestAttribute), true).Length > 0)
            {
                List<ITool> args = new List<ITool>();
                args.Add(tool);
                result.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(type, args));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

ToolTestAttribute code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Sharpline.SL24.ToolingAddIn.Attributes
{
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class ToolTestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Target;
    public string Name;

        public ToolTestAttribute(string testTarget, string testName)
        {
            Target = testTarget;
            Name = testName;
        }

    }
}
```

My args list has a single element of the correct type.
What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type, params object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___) overload.

This takes an *object array* of constructor parameters to pass. Your constructor is expecting an `ITool`, but you're trying to pass a `List<ITool>` as the first parameter.

Either do:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type, tool)
```

Or:

```
object[] args = new object[] { tool };
Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
```

Comment: I guess I'll give the answer to the first poster since four all said the same basic thing. So I grabbed the wrongActivator.Instance overload. So if I had a constructor that took more than one parameter I suppose that THEN I would use the array?

Comment: @EricSnyder You grabbed the right overload -- you just missed that you can't pass a `List<T>` of arguments. Either you pass the arguments one-by-one (without an array or list, etc, wrapping them), or you pass an `object[]` of arguments. `Activator.CreateInstance` doesn't know how to interpret a `List<T>` of arguments

Answer (score 2):

The `CreateInstance` method that you're using takes a `Type` and a `params object[]`; since you're giving it a *list* (not an array), you're essentially saying "find a constructor that has a parameter that *is a list*".

try instead:

```cs
object[] args = new object[] { tool };
result.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(type, args));
```

or perhaps simpler, let the compiler deal with it:

```cs
result.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(type, tool));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___) does not take a `List<ITool>` argument, but a variable number of objects (`params object[]`).

So your code tries to call a constructor that takes a `List<ITool>` which does not exist.

Change it to: `Activator.CreateInstance(type, tool)`

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `List<ITool>` as the first parameter, not an `ITool`. Try this instead:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type, tool);
```

The overload of `CreateInstance` that you are calling is a `params object[] args`, so what you were doing was trying to pass `List<ITool>` as the first parameter.